# How to sign unsigned assembly in a nuget package?

Tags: nuget

The problem is that: We need to deploy our application using ClickOnce. We signed our own assemblies in order to do that, BUT we are using some nuget packages that have their assemblies not signed. So now our app crashes complaining about signed assemblies referencing unsigned ones. The nuget package does not seems to have a signed version. How do we deal with that situation? Is there a way to continue using nuget and make the assemblies somehow signed, without the need to manually reference custom signed assemblies as suggested in some other answers? Is there a nuget setting that tells the package manager to sign the assemblies on install or something like that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using the [StrongNamer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/strongnamer) NuGet package.

> It will transparently and automatically sign the assemblies you reference as part of the build process.

Comment: Wow, great and simple solution! I feared I had to sign them manually using some obscure console commands.